# Can't access correctly to tracepoint context struct fields

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf, tracepoint

**GOAL:** write in the trace_pipe only if openat is called with O_RDONLY flag. I've build the struct looking the format contained here /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_open/format

**PROBLEM** I think I'm not accessing to the flags field  because it looks like that the second if statement is always false.
**QUESTION:** am I correctly accessing to the flags fields? Is there a way to print flags variable content?

```
struct syscalls_enter_openat_args {
    __u64 pad;
    int __syscall_nr;
    const char * filename;
    int flags;
    unsigned short modep;
};
SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_openat")
int bpf_sys(struct syscalls_enter_openat_args *ctx)
{
    char fmt[] = "llo\n";
    int flags = ctx->flags;

    if (flags){
        if (flags == O_RDONLY)
            bpf_trace_printk(fmt, sizeof(fmt)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

Comment: Not sure this is the cause of your issue, but usually you check a flag with `flags & O_RDONLY`, not `==`, just in case `flags` also contains other flags. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mention that the following check always evaluates to false:

```c
if (flags == O_RDONLY)
```

This may be because there are more flags than just `O_RDONLY` that are passed to `openat()` through the variable `flags`. From the `openat()` manual page:

> The argument *flags* must include one of the following *access modes*: `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`.  These request opening the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.
>
> In  addition,  zero  or  more  file  creation flags and file status flags can be bitwise-*or*'d in *flags*.  The *file creation flags* are `O_CLOEXEC`, `O_CREAT`, `O_DIRECTORY`, `O_EXCL`, `O_NOCTTY`, `O_NOFOLLOW`, `O_TMPFILE`, and `O_TRUNC`.  The file status flags are all of the remaining flags listed below.  The distinction between these two groups of flags is that the file creation flags affect the semantics of the open operation itself, while the file status flags affect the semantics of subsequent I/O operations.  The *file status flags* can be retrieved and (in some cases) modified; see `fcntl(2)` for details.

So instead of checking if your `flags` are *equal* to `O_RDONLY`, you might want to check if they *include* the flag, by bit-masking it like this:

```c
if (flags & O_RDONLY)
```

As for printing the value of `flags`, it is probably doable with something like this (not tested):

```c
        char fmt[] = "flags: %x\n";
        int flags = ctx->flags;

        if (flags & O_RDONLY)
                bpf_trace_printk(fmt, sizeof(fmt), flags);
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway I have a doubt, If I strace the program the call to openat includes ONLY O_RDONLY , no other flags are used. So I'd expecte flags=O_RDONLY

Comment: Yeah, maybe you just have `O_RDONLY` (in which case checking with `==` should work indeed), and this was not the cause of your issue. Is your BPF program successfully loaded (`bpftool prog`)? Successfully attached (try `bpftool perf`)? Can you see messages from `bpf_trace_printk()` when `openat()` is run? Can you print the value for `flags` from your BPF program?